# Are legs a choice?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

> Legs are a choice in that we could choose not to have them by cutting them off.

Is it correct here to use the word *choice* meaning "an option"?

Is it correct to say that legs are a choice I could use to get to work instead of using the choice of a car?

Comment: This is a matter of philosophy, not really of language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both of your questions. People say those things.

Strictly speaking, choices and options are different things, but in normal spoken and written English, they're usually considered interchangeable. Only peevish pedants would dispute that, except where stipulated that they're different.

You can replace "legs" with "shank's mare".

I don't think I'd say "Legs are a choice I could use to get to work instead of using the choice of a car". It's verbose and a bit awkward. I'd probably write "Legs, instead of a car, are an option for getting to work".

Comment: I've always known it as [shank's pony](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shank%27s+mare%2Cshank%27s+pony&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), but comparing that British corpus NGram to [the American one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shank%27s+mare%2Cshank%27s+pony&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) it seems there's a significant UK/US split on usage here.

Comment: I saw the shank's pony possibility on a [reference.com page](http://ask.reference.com/web?s=t&q=shank's%20mare&l=dir&qsrc=2891&o=10300). It's from a UK ask.com page. I'd never heard or read it before, so I'd have to agree that there's a significant split.